# Why do I see "Type Error: cursor is undefined" when using indexedDB?

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I am trying to use an index.openCursor(keyRange.only or keyRange.bound Provided here) to access one or more records using an index on a table created with **autoIncrement: true**.  I have tried multiple variations with no success.  Can someone show me a working example using the following code as a template:

```
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB 
                || window.mozIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
var ixDb; 

var ixDbIndexTest = function () {
  //Open or create the requested IndexedDB Database
  var ixDbRequest = window.indexedDB.open("testDBindexes", 2);

  ixDbRequest.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
    ixDb = ixDbRequest.result || e.currentTarget.result;

    objectStore = 
      ixDb.createObjectStore("demoOS", 
                             { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
    objectStore.createIndex("ixdemo", "Field1",
                             { unique: false, multiEntry: false });

    //define new dummy record  
    var newRecord = {};
    newRecord.Field1 = "222";
    newRecord.Field2 = "333";
    newRecord.Field3 = "444";

    var request = objectStore.add(newRecord);

    request.onsuccess = function (e) {
      var index = objectStore.index('ixdemo');
      var range = IDBKeyRange.only("222");
      var cursorRequest = index.openCursor(range);

      cursorRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {    
        var cursor = cursorRequest.result || e.result; 
        alert(cursor.value);
        cursor.continue();
      }
    }
  };
};

window.onload = ixDbIndexTest;
```

**Update:**
I modified the demo script to work in both Firefox and older Chrome versions that still use setVersion. However, you would need to add additional version checking logic for Chrome since the current logic runs setVersion every time the script runs.

```
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB 
                || window.mozIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
window.IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction 
                    || window.mozIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction;
window.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || 
                     window.mozIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange;

var ixDb;     
var ixDbIndexTest = function () {
  //Open or create the requested IndexedDB Database
  var ixDbRequest = window.indexedDB.open("testDBindexes", 1);

  ixDbRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
    ixDb = ixDbRequest.result || e.currentTarget.result;

    if (typeof ixDb.setVersion === "function") {
      ixDbVersionRequest = ixDb.setVersion(1);

      ixDbVersionRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
        indexTest();
      };
     }
     else {
       ixDbRequest.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
       indexTest(); 
       };
     }
   }
 };

window.onload = ixDbIndexTest;

function indexTest() {
  var objectStore = ixDb.createObjectStore("demoOS", 
                           { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
  objectStore.createIndex("ixdemo", "Field1", 
                           { unique: false, multiEntry: false });

  //define new record with users input 
  var newRecord = {};
  newRecord.Field1 = "222";
  newRecord.Field2 = "333";
  newRecord.Field3 = "444";

  var request = objectStore.add(newRecord);

  request.onsuccess = function (e) {
    var index = objectStore.index('ixdemo');
    var range = IDBKeyRange.only("222");
    var cursorRequest = index.openCursor();

    cursorRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {    
      var cursor = cursorRequest.result || e.result; 
      if(cursor) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(cursor.value));
        cursor.continue();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point, but your code seems to work. It displays the entry in the database. What exactly is your problem? Is there an error message or something?

Comment: @Jeremy you are correct about the record adding.  However, the index does not appear to be working correctly, or I am not using it correctly???  When I look in the web console in Firefox, I am getting the error message "Type Error: cursor is undefined".  I cannot seem to return a cursor using a range.bound() or range.only() via the index.openCursor() call.

Comment: In addition, when I run this code in Chrome via the setVersion command, you can see record added, but the index never appears to be populated with each insert.  I have tried adding keyPath: id and still cannot get it working.

Comment: When I add the keyPath: id to the createObjectStore command, then the add() call expects { id: value } to be provided in the object that I send, and the autoincrement no longer "autoincrements"...

Comment: If I change the alert as follows: alert(JSON.stringify(cursor.value)); I do get a record value back in Firefox, but I still get the TypeError: "Cursor is not defined"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message `Type Error: cursor is undefined` happens because you are using the cursor without checking to see if it's defined. So when `cursor.continue()` tells IndexedDB to go get the next object in the database, the cursor will be undefined after it exhausts the only object that actually exists.

So you should do something like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB#Using_a_cursor). In your code, it would look like:

```
      cursorRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {    
        var cursor = cursorRequest.result || e.result;
        if (cursor) {
          alert(cursor.value);
          cursor.continue();
        }
      }
```

Also, if you know you are only looking for one object (like when you use `IDBKeyRange.only`), you can just omit the `cursor.continue()` part:

```
      cursorRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {    
        var cursor = cursorRequest.result || e.result;
        alert(cursor.value);
      }
```

As for your problem With Chrome, I can't help you there as I've only focused on Firefox so far. I would recommend you try the latest development version of Chrome, which actually does support `onupgradeneeded` along with various other updates, but in my testing so far it's still pretty buggy and code that works in Firefox can fail in Chrome. You might be better off just waiting some time for Chrome to stabilize, if this isn't an urgent project.

Comment: I was able to update the script to work in the production version of Chrome as well.  The reason it was failing was related to the IDBKeyRange being undefined.  I was able to resolve this by adding the following code:  window.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.mozIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange;  I will update my question with the revised JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add records while in onupgardeneeded event.

after versing change, you must reopen the database to get new objectStore schema. so there will be two open

current chrome is, i think still old standard, setVersion, onupgardeneeded is never call.

newRecord must have keyPath 'id' or you should not specified keyPath in creating object store.

Comment: You can add records within `onupgradeneeded`. See [this example form Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB#Structuring_the_database), for instance. Chrome 23 supports `onupgradeneeded`. And you don't need to specify `id` if it's autoincrementing, which it is.

Comment: I agree with Jeremy, the code above does add the record in Firefox.  Your response does not answer the question either.  I am looking for a working example that opens a cursor via an index, using a keyRange on an autoincrement: true table.

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks. With my previous experience with chrome, database have to be reopen to work with newly created ObjectStore.